# What limitations (if any) would I face developing asp.net on OSX? (in 2015/2016)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm a diehard mac lover but my day to day work is shifting towards the .net stack, specifically c#, asp.net mvc, entity framework, multiple project class libraries, ms test, sql server, deployment to azure.

In light of the recent cross platform advancements in .net, what issues (if any) would I face now and later on as I get deeper into development? Is anyone else doing this?

I've installed VSCode (https://code.visualstudio.com) and am able to build and run an asp.net mvc web app using coreclr. That seems to work very well and is closer to the web development experience I'm used to on a mac. I understand I also get vs.net style debugging with VSCode but I've yet to test that.

SQL Server I realise will be a problem, I'm considering either running it in a VM or using a cloud based dev instance.

I've also trialed running full vs.net in a VM but on my 13" MBP i5 8GB it gets a tiny bit sluggish at times under VMWare Fusion, so not ideal. VSCode also gives me a dev experience much closer to what I've been doing previously from my mac (simple text editor, terminal etc) so I prefer that anyway.

So, can I do this? is cross platform .net ready for mid sized asp.net apps? what problems may I run into? I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: What's your definition of mid sized?

Comment: why was this put on hold? seems like a valid question simly asking what obstacles one might encounter when developing asp.net app on mac osx.

Comment: @LexLi - that's pretty difficult to quantify, I guess 150~ controllers, 200~ models, 50k loc? ish

Comment: @Woland the wonders of modern day stack overflow

Comment: Its not a matter of opinion on whether its possible or not. It either is or isn't, and its a rapidly changing landscape in terms of .net embracing cross platform so I think many programmers will be asking the same questions.

Comment: @matthewrk yes, it is very odd, seems like people who flagged the post didn't even read it, atleast there is one answer that helps and it looks like VM is the only way to go currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've already installed VS Code on your Mac, you already know that you can work on ASP.NET projects natively on your Mac. Just keep in mind you can run the cross-platform .NET Core 5 on your Mac, but not the full .NET Framework. So, if you need to work on any projects that need the full framework (such as .NET 4.x), you will need to use Windows. It doesn't matter if it's small, midsized or large enterprise apps.

As you suggested, you can run Windows on your Mac. But instead of VMWare, I would suggest Parallels instead. Running Windows on your Mac will allow you to run the full Visual Studio with the full .NET framework if that's what you need. It would also let you run SQL Server on Windows inside your Mac.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Shahed, I have run into one issue where EF7 doesn't quite have some of the features we'd need yet, as they've cut some for later releases, so we're stuck with EF6 which is of course not cross platform! ouch. So maybe not quite ready for prime time OS X development just yet in my case, at least not without VM's.

Comment: That's correct. While EF6 and 7 are both open source, only EF7 is cross-platform. Best of luck on your project and don't forget to mark my response as the answer if you found it useful. Thanks! :)